# If statement using vhdl

Tags: if-statement, vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I am designing counter using vhdl using planahead software, anyway I am using if statment but it gave many errors . the purpose of the counter is to count Ascending/Descending from 1 to 10 and the opposite. In case of Ascending I reset the out when it get to 9 to count again from 0. And in case Descending reset the out when it gets 0 and give 9 as new value . and I am using switch button on the board to switch between Ascending/Descending counting. Below the if statment and the errors . I dont know if I use it on the write form . Plz if anyone have an idea would be perfect.

```
 Line:27-   if(inc_dec='1') then
 Line:28    if (r_reg=M-1) then
            r_next<=(others=>'0')
 Line:30    else r_reg+1;
 Line: 31   elsif (inc_dec='0')then
 Line:32    if (r_reg=M-10) then
            r_next<=(others=>'9')
 Line:34    else
            r_reg-1;

           end if;
           end if;
           end if;
```

---

### The errors :

```
 Line:27 [HDLCompiler 806] Syntax error near "if". 
 Line:28[HDLCompiler 806] Syntax error near "then". 
 Line:30[HDLCompiler 806] Syntax error near "else". 
 Line:31[HDLCompiler 806] Syntax error near "then". 

 Line:32[HDLCompiler 806] Syntax error near "then". 
 Line:34[HDLCompiler 806] Syntax error near "else".
```

Comment: You can't have `else` followed by `elsif` without an `end if` for the `else`.  But from the error messages it looks like you try to use `if` statement at a wrong place, maybe outside a process.  Please post the original source code.

Comment: Format this code properly and the error will probably be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [Morten Zilmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2352082/morten-zilmer), you need to terminate the if/else with an end if. Also there have been some missing semicolons. The code below should work.

```
if (inc_dec='1') then
   if (r_reg=(M-1)) then
        r_next <= (others=>'0');
   else 
        r_reg+1;
   end if; 
elsif (inc_dec='0') then
   if (r_reg=(M-10)) then
        r_next <=  to_unsigned(9, r_next'length);
   else
        r_reg-1;
   end if;
end if;
```

Update: [Jonathan Drolet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4577314/jonathan-drolet) is right. Changed

```
r_next <= (others=>'9');
```

to

```
r_next <=  to_unsigned(9, r_next'length)
```

in the code

Comment: The line r_next <= (others => '9') is erroneous. Correct expression is r_next <= to_unsigned(9, r_next'length) if using the numeric_std package.

Comment: yes, How I forgot the (others=>'9');. Itz totally incorrect . Thnks you I am goint to try this code